# TikZ: Is it possible to use ocgx or ocgx2 with scaling?

Tags: tikz-pgf, ocg, ocgx2, ocgx

To get a handout, I drew polygons on A4 paper arranged in landscape mode.
In order to create an interactive slide show with beamer associated with these documents, I had to reduce the dimensions with `scale=.25` so that all the figures appear on the slide.
To simplify the demonstration, the polygons have been replaced by rectangles.

Handout code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\draw[thick](0,4)rectangle(21,10);
\draw[thick](24,-10)rectangle(39,-3);
\draw[thick](24,0)rectangle(34,10);% carré
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The beamer code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer} % Présentation générale et mise en page
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}            

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test ocgx2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
\draw[switch ocg=Un,thick](0,4)rectangle(21,10);
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=Un,ref=Un,status=invisible},every path/.style={blue,line width=.8pt}]
\draw[fill=green!30](0,4)rectangle(21,10);
\end{scope}

\draw[switch ocg=Deux,thick](24,-10)rectangle(39,-3);
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=Deux,ref=Deux,status=invisible},every path/.style={blue,line width=.8pt}]
\draw[fill=green!30](24,-10)rectangle(39,-3);
\end{scope}

\draw[thick,switch ocg=Trois](24,0)rectangle(34,10);% squarre
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=Trois,ref=Trois,status=invisible},every path/.style={blue,line width=.5pt}]
\draw[fill=green!30](24,0)rectangle(34,10);% carré
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Each rectangle is interactive. By clicking on it, it is colored alternately green or white (action `\switchocg`). When scaled, the interactive area overlaps with the other rectangles and becomes inactive.
For example, by clicking on the lower rectangle, the upper rectangle link is activated.

Is it possible to use `ocgx` or `ocgx2` with scaling?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

[image: ocgx2 test]

Comment: I apologize in advance if that's nonsense, I really do not know what `ocgx` does. But I *think* I got a different (or better behavior) by using `\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.25,0)},y={(0,0.25)}]` instead of `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]`. Could you perhaps check?

Comment: @marmot Thank you so much, it works great, can you make it a solution?

Comment: Fixed in `ocgx2` as of v. 0.35. See below.

Comment: Version 0.36 is available on MikTeX today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the current versions of the `ocgx` and `ocgx2` packages.

A new [↗**`ocgx2`**](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx2) version (0.35 2018/06/26) is on the way to CTAN. In the meantime, the fixed file `ocgx2.sty` can be downloaded [↗here](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/ocgx2/raw/master/ocgx2.sty).

---

Background:

TikZ paths are turned into clickable PDF-Layer switching links by overlaying the link-making command (`\switchocg...`) onto the bounding box of the current path as a TikZ-`postaction`. Command `\switchocg...` needs a text-box of appropriate size as its 2nd argument in order to create the mouse sensitive rectangle. Originally, a `\rule` placed in a `\phantom` was used whose width and height were calculated from the bounding box lower-left and upper-right corner coordinates. The result was saved in `\p3` (see diff below). However, `\p3` does not seem to be subject to scaling if used in the `node` object of `path picture`. Instead, we create coordinates `(p1)` and `(p2)` from `\p1` and `\p2` and use them directly in the nested `tikzpicture`:

```
\tikz \useasboundingbox (p1) rectangle (p2);
```

Excerpt from the diff between the fixed and the old `ocgx2.sty` version:

```
   switch ocg/.style={
     postaction={
       path picture={
         \path let
         \p1 = (path picture bounding box.south west),
-        \p2 = (path picture bounding box.north east),
-        \p3 = (\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)
+        \p2 = (path picture bounding box.north east)
         in
-        (path picture bounding box.center)
-        node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=center,outer sep=0pt]
-        {\switchocg*{#1}{\phantom{\rule{\x3}{\y3}}}};
+        coordinate (p1) at (\p1) coordinate (p2) at (\p2)
+        node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west,outer sep=0pt] at (p1)
+        {\switchocg*{#1}{\tikz \useasboundingbox (p1) rectangle (p2);}};
       }
     }
   },
```

Comment: Cool. +1. That's a really quick fix!

Comment: Thanks for this quick fix, so I accept your solution and thank @marmot for its solution.

Comment: Hope it won't make @marmot angry. Thank you for reporting the issue! (And +1 for marmot, in order to appease him/her.)

Comment: I just tested the new version and the bug is indeed fixed. A thousand thanks to you and @marmot

Comment: Thanks! Could you perhaps tell us briefly what went wrong?

Comment: @marmot When I downloaded the new file, I saved it directly in the `/tex/latex/ocgx2` folder with `save as`. But since the MikTeX folder is write-protected under Windows, nothing has been saved. I recorded it in `administrator mode` with notepad++.
And I was able to verify that the bug is fixed.

Comment: @AndréC I have no doubt that it is fixed. I was just wondering if the culprit was some sort of hard coded distance.

Comment: @marmot Explanation added.

Comment: On CTAN the version is 0.36, not 0.35. What's new here?

Comment: 2nd  update since yesterday :-) Just simplified the code a bit.

Answer (score 5):

I have to admit that I a have not even heard about the `ocgx(2)` packages before looking at this question. So I cannot really explain why, but it seems that replacing `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]` by `\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.25,0)},y={(0,0.25)}]` does the trick. (Of course I understand how these options differ, that's why I tried that out, but again I do not know the details of the `ocgx(2)` packages to tell what goes wrong if one uses `scale`.)

The complete MWE thus becomes:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer} % Présentation générale et mise en page
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}            

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test ocgx2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.25,0)},y={(0,0.25)}]
\draw[switch ocg=Un,thick](0,4)rectangle(21,10);
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=Un,ref=Un,status=invisible},every path/.style={blue,line width=.8pt}]
\draw[fill=green!30](0,4)rectangle(21,10);
\end{scope}

\draw[switch ocg=Deux,thick](24,-10)rectangle(39,-3);
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=Deux,ref=Deux,status=invisible},every path/.style={blue,line width=.8pt}]
\draw[fill=green!30](24,-10)rectangle(39,-3);
\end{scope}

\draw[thick,switch ocg=Trois](24,0)rectangle(34,10);% squarre
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=Trois,ref=Trois,status=invisible},every path/.style={blue,line width=.5pt}]
\draw[fill=green!30](24,0)rectangle(34,10);% carré
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `ocgx2` package is the continuity of the `ocgx` package and integrates the `ocg`, `ocg-p` packages. It allows you to create interactive PDF files. See a demonstration here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx/demo-ocgx.pdf

Comment: @AndréC Thanks! (This I also figured in the meantime.) I *guess* that the problem is that there is somewhere some distance is hard coded, to see what I mean compare `\tikz[scale=0.25]{\draw(0,0)--(1cm,0);}` to `\tikz[x={(0.25,0)}]{\draw(0,0)--(1cm,0);}`. But I am far from being sure about that.

Comment: Each rectangle is interactive. By clicking on each, it is coloured green or white.  With `scale`, the interactive zone is that of the path coded in hard and thus exceeds the rectangle since the latter is scaled.
With the other solution, the interactive zone is that of the rectangle and nothing but this zone.

Comment: The workaround is not necessary anymore, with `ocgx2` v. 0.35.